# Java. Collections. Partition by page limit

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

Trying to find the right way into doing such a thing using Stream/Collectors:

I have a bucket type wrapper (let it have StringBuilder under the hood), which has a char limit (25 characters per bucket).

I have an input stream of entries, which meet the requirement of being less than 20 symbols.

Each stream entry is processed with a `.map(...)` operation, adding a `*` to the end of an entry.

I want to partition (if this is the right word for this case) a stream of such entries and collect them to buckets, without loosing integrity, by the means of Collectors.

Input:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Output:

```
---- bucket 1 ----
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa *
    aaaaaa *
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa *
---- bucket 2 ----
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa *
```

I know how to achieve this using regular loops, by how to do it using Stream/Collectors?

Comment: example = `1,2,3,4` becomes `[ [1,2],[3,4] ]`  Is this what you want??

Comment: in the very basic approach - yes. I want to collect elements of the stream to a state container, which will be replaced by a new one once some condition is made. Better to imagine this as a "I want to place multiple images to a word document page, and once a page no longer has room, move to another page"

Comment: @Holger, I want to take elements, make some string based transformation, and then store them in wrappers, which have character limitations. Meaning, if I have a bucket, which already has 199/200 char limit fulfilled, I want to replace the current bucket with a new one. The linkedList and stuff is not relevant, and was written as a mere example of the flow that I'm trying to make using Collectors.

Comment: Ok, removed the previous version of the question. See if this version is correct.

Comment: When you “know how to achieve this using regular loops”, you should include this. As a working code example can document the task better than most prose. Further, when no built-in collector for a task exist, the code of a custom collector will share a lot with the code of the loop body anyway, which makes it a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way:

You stream over the indices of the input `List`, and you group the indices by dividing them by the `limit`.

```
List<String> input = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d");
int limit = 2;
Collection<List<String>> split =
    IntStream.range(0,input.size())
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i / limit,
                                            Collectors.mapping(input::get,
                                            Collectors.toList())))
             .values();
System.out.println (split);
```

Output:

```
[[a, b], [c, d]]
```

Changing `limit` to 3 will change the output to:

```
[[a, b, c], [d]]
```

Of course you can easily transform the `Collection<List<String>>` to a `List<List<String>>` if you wish (by calling `List<List<String>> splitList = new ArrayList<>(split);`).

Comment: The size of List needs to be even... what if it becomes odd??

Comment: @VishwaRatna what do you mean? The size of which List?

Comment: `input` List I mean.

Comment: @VishwaRatna why? If you change the input to `Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d","e")`, the output becomes `[[a, b], [c, d], [e]]`.

Comment: I saw this example, but the thing is that I'm trying to achieve something different here - I want to have read the state of the target collector (the collection, which is currently being filled) and determine if the current item of the list can be added to it (or should it be added to a new collector collection). Best example would be trying to paste multiple images to a word document, resolving that the current page has enough room to for the next image, and, if not, moved to a new page).

Comment: @AppleBuckler my suggested code will produce the same output as the code you posted. If that's not the output you need, perhaps you should edit your question. Why does it matter if the target Collection/List is created in advance or produced by the Stream pipeline?

Comment: Yes, guess I'll need to change the question. Thanks